# How to make plugin components function available as Rest API in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

In one of the components of my plugin, I've got a function which reads user input (using `Input::get()`), creates a `Model` and saves it to the database. The data is submitted to this function via a html form. Now I want to allow users to add new data via `Rest API` too. So I create a file called `routes.php` in the root directory of my plugin and define a route for posting data. As it's logical to reuse the code that is already available in my plugins component, I tried to map the route to the already available component function:

```
Route::post('/items', 'Acme\Plugin\Components\ItemsList@addItem');
```

But this does not work and I get the following error:

> The component Acme\Plugin\Components\ItemsList does not contain a method getAfterFilters

Is this how the code should be reused in my Rest API? Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Acme\Plugin\Components\ItemsList implements some interface, and you must have a method getAfterFilters  in it. or do not implement from that interface.

Comment: @Asheliahut It extends `ComponentBase`, as all components do in OctoberCMS.

Answer (score 2):

make a controller with no extend and use dependency injection for the component in the constructor

or

extend from

```
Illuminate\Routing\Controller
```

and dependecy injection

you can use the `"Route::resource"` function